# JSON naming convention in different object

Tags: json, naming-conventions

I know the following two json string are valid, but which one may be better? I think the second one can display more information when I get the field name, however, I am afraid that if I follow these naming rule, the field name might be very long. I hope someone who had considered these designs could give me some suggestions, many thanks!

Case1:

```
{
  "applicant": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
  },
  "insured": {
    "name": "Marry",
    "age": 25
  }
}
```

Case2:

```
{
  "applicant": {
    "applicantName": "John",
    "applicantAge": 30
  },
  "insured": {
    "insuredName": "Marry",
    "insuredAge": 25
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the longer notation:

- is redundant
- makes the codebase more verbose which can make you lose more time on typing and can sometimes make it harder to read
- makes it harder to reuse the same objects as you would need to constantly remap properties (i.e. if you wanted to have the same `applicant` and `insured`, you would need to remap `applicantName` to `insuredName` and `applicantAge` to `insuredAge`, along with other properties you might have).
- makes it harder to reuse any existing code which was made to manipulate an instance of `Applicant` or `Insured` because even though the field names may have the same meanings, they are not named the same.

I would prefer the shorter notation and would remap the properties to the longer one only when I would need a flattened object which can sometimes be useful in some MVC/MVVM frameworks such as KnockoutJS. For example, I would use:

```
{
  "applicant": {
    "name": "John",
    "age": 30
  },
  "insured": {
    "name": "Marry",
    "age": 25
  }
}
```

and would remap to:

```
{
  "applicantName": "John",
  "applicantAge": 30,
  "insuredName": "Marry",
  "insuredAge": 25
}
```

only when I would need it.

Having said that, I would also try to keep the variable names in my code easy to understand - I would always name my array of applicants `applicants` or `applicantsList` and not `data` or `items` so everybody (including myself) who reads my code always knows what's it about.